# if functions radio submit

Tags: php, if-statement

Need a little help with doing stuff witha radio selection.
In PHP
I am setting up a form with 4 selections.

```
<form name='type'action=<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Select one of the following:<br>
<input type='radio' value= '*' name='all'> All Memebers this season<br>
<input type='radio' value= 'L' name='league'> All Members of a League<br>
<input type='radio' value= 'T' name='team'> All Members of a Team<br>
<input type='radio' value= 'I' name='individual'> Individual player<br>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'><br />
```

My thoughts are to perform different queries based upon the selection.

So if all members is selected, query `select * from table` is run.

If League is selected I would get a drop dpwn list of `select * from league`

If team is selected I would get a drop down from the Team list

if memebers is selected I would get a drop down of all members.

then when one of the drop downs is selected Or if all is selected, it would take info and send out emails.

I can handle the queries just unsure of if I have to send to different pages, and how to handle an if statement with multiple entries.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You seriously need to improve your writing.

Comment: @mathielo I apologize for my writing skills.

Comment: @STLMikey I thought the question was clear, perhaps too much detail. My question is how can I construct an if statement that will do something different based upon what is selected in the form.

Comment: I see one mistake...I didn't assign the same name for the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Give all the radio buttons the same name, different values.
2. Set the form method to "post" or "get," in this case I'm using "get."

So...

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Select one of the following:<br />
<input type='radio' value= 'A' name='selected'> All Memebers this season<br />
<input type='radio' value= 'L' name='selected'> All Members of a League<br />
<input type='radio' value= 'T' name='selected'> All Members of a Team<br />
<input type='radio' value= 'I' name='selected'> Individual player<br />
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'><br />
```

Then your code would be...

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['selected'] == 'A') {**SQL LOOP CODE HERE**}
else if ($_GET['selected'] == 'L') {**SQL LOOP CODE HERE**}
else if ($_GET['selected'] == 'T') {**SQL LOOP CODE HERE**}
else if ($_GET['selected'] == 'I') {**SQL LOOP CODE HERE**}
else {echo 'No selection made.';}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I realized the naming error and added the method. In my previous attempts I lost track of the {}es. I still have a lot of bugs to work out.